# javafx HBox move elements around

Tags: javafx

got this

```
  package net.makerimages.starling.src.window;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import net.makerimages.starling.src.Main;

 /**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Kodukas
 * Date: 29.11.13
 * Time: 23:53
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class TopBar extends HBox
{
public Button closeButton;
public Button minMaxButton;
public Label titleLabel;

public TopBar()
{
    titleLabel=new Label("Starling browser");
    closeButton=new Button("X");

    closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    });
    closeButton.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 0.9;");

    minMaxButton=new Button("|  |");
    minMaxButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            if(Main.stg.isFullScreen()==false)
            {
                 Main.stg.setFullScreen(true);
                minMaxButton.setText("||");
            }
            else if(Main.stg.isFullScreen()==true)
            {
                Main.stg.setFullScreen(false);
                minMaxButton.setText("|  |");
                Main.browser.setMaxHeight(Main.browser.getHeight()-20);
            }
        }
    });



    this.getChildren().addAll(closeButton,minMaxButton);
    this.getChildren().add(titleLabel);
    setMargin(titleLabel,new Insets(0,10,0,0));


}
}
```

What I would like to have is the buttons on the right and the label in the centre, however anything I`ve tried for that has not worked.(this is used as a toolbar in a borderPane)
 Ive tried literally everything I know of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `StackPane` as the base container for your toolbar. Add a `Label` and a `HBox` to the StackPane. The Label will automatically be aligned to the center. Add the buttons to the HBox; on the HBox set the alignment property to `TOP_RIGHT`. Set padding, spacing etc. as needed.

It's very helpful to use SceneBuilder for experimenting with layouts like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use a `GridPane` and add the elements to the row and column they need them to be in.